# Simplest TBB example

Tags: c++, tbb, icc

Can someone give me a [TBB](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Threading_Building_Blocks) example how to:

1. set the maximum count of active threads.
2. execute tasks that are independent from each others and presented in the form of class, not static functions.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a couple of complete examples, one using `parallel_for`, the other using `parallel_for_each`.

**Update 2014-04-12**: These show what I'd consider to be a pretty old fashioned way of using TBB now; I've added a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607215/simplest-tbb-example/23027877#23027877) using `parallel_for` with a C++11 lambda.

```
#include "tbb/blocked_range.h"
#include "tbb/parallel_for.h"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct mytask {
  mytask(size_t n)
    :_n(n)
  {}
  void operator()() {
    for (int i=0;i<1000000;++i) {}  // Deliberately run slow
    std::cerr << "[" << _n << "]";
  }
  size_t _n;
};

struct executor
{
  executor(std::vector<mytask>& t)
    :_tasks(t)
  {}
  executor(executor& e,tbb::split)
    :_tasks(e._tasks)
  {}

  void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r) const {
    for (size_t i=r.begin();i!=r.end();++i)
      _tasks[i]();
  }

  std::vector<mytask>& _tasks;
};

int main(int,char**) {

  tbb::task_scheduler_init init;  // Automatic number of threads
  // tbb::task_scheduler_init init(2);  // Explicit number of threads

  std::vector<mytask> tasks;
  for (int i=0;i<1000;++i)
    tasks.push_back(mytask(i));

  executor exec(tasks);
  tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0,tasks.size()),exec);
  std::cerr << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include "tbb/parallel_for_each.h"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct mytask {
  mytask(size_t n)
    :_n(n)
  {}
  void operator()() {
    for (int i=0;i<1000000;++i) {}  // Deliberately run slow
    std::cerr << "[" << _n << "]";
  }
  size_t _n;
};

template <typename T> struct invoker {
  void operator()(T& it) const {it();}
};

int main(int,char**) {

  tbb::task_scheduler_init init;  // Automatic number of threads
  // tbb::task_scheduler_init init(4);  // Explicit number of threads

  std::vector<mytask> tasks;
  for (int i=0;i<1000;++i)
    tasks.push_back(mytask(i));

  tbb::parallel_for_each(tasks.begin(),tasks.end(),invoker<mytask>());
  std::cerr << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Both compile on a Debian/Wheezy (g++ 4.7) system with `g++ tbb_example.cpp -ltbb` (then run with `./a.out`)

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610307/am-i-reinventing-the-wheel-with-this-trivial-method-call-forwarding-class) for replacing that "`invoker`" thing with a `std::mem_fun_ref` or `boost::bind`).

Comment: Note that `tbb::task_scheduler_init` was removed by Intel in oneAPI/oneTBB on GitHub. `oneapi::tbb::global_control c(oneapi::tbb::global_control::max_allowed_parallelism, 6);` seems to be "the new way".

Answer (score 22):

Here's a more modern use of `parallel_for` with a lambda; compiles and runs on Debian/Wheezy with `g++ -std=c++11 tbb_example.cpp -ltbb && ./a.out`:

```
#include "tbb/parallel_for.h"
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct mytask {
  mytask(size_t n)
    :_n(n)
  {}
  void operator()() {
    for (int i=0;i<1000000;++i) {}  // Deliberately run slow
    std::cerr << "[" << _n << "]";
  }
  size_t _n;
};

int main(int,char**) {

  //tbb::task_scheduler_init init;  // Automatic number of threads
  tbb::task_scheduler_init init(tbb::task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads());  // Explicit number of threads

  std::vector<mytask> tasks;
  for (int i=0;i<1000;++i)
    tasks.push_back(mytask(i));

  tbb::parallel_for(
    tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0,tasks.size()),
    [&tasks](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r) {
      for (size_t i=r.begin();i<r.end();++i) tasks[i]();
    }
  );

  std::cerr << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to run a couple of tasks concurrently, it might be easier to just use a `tbb::task_group`. Example taken from [tbb](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_groups/task_group_cls.htm):

```
#include "tbb/task_group.h"  

using namespace tbb;

int Fib(int n) {
    if( n<2 ) {
        return n;
    } else {
        int x, y;
        task_group g;
        g.run([&]{x=Fib(n-1);}); // spawn a task
        g.run([&]{y=Fib(n-2);}); // spawn another task
        g.wait();                // wait for both tasks to complete
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

Note however that

> Creating a large number of tasks for a single task_group is not scalable, because task creation becomes a serial bottleneck.

In those cases, use timday's examples with a `parallel_for` or alike.

Answer (score 1):

1-

```
 //!
 //! Get the default number of threads
 //!
 int nDefThreads = tbb::task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads();

 //!
 //! Init the task scheduler with the wanted number of threads
 //!
 tbb::task_scheduler_init init(nDefThreads);
```

2-

Maybe if your code permits, the best way to run independent task with TBB is the [parallel_invoke](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_invoke_func.htm). In the blog of intel developers zone there is a post explaining some cases of how helpfull parallel_invoke could be. Check out [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/04/02/running-your-code-in-parallel-with-tbbparallel_invoke)