# Efficient loop multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop

I have a function which takes an integer and then runs for some time (5-500 seconds depending on function input).

`void foo(int parameter) { /*do some staff*/ }`

Results of this calculation are stored in text file created by this function.

> resultsFor{parameter}.txt

Then i have a for loop which evaluates this function for given set of integers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   foo(i);
```

Now I want to optimize computing time for this loop with threads. Preferably using std library.

```
#include <thread>
```

At first I want to create certain number of threads which would be equal to number of cores of current machine.

```
numberOfThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

**And then I want to assign those threads to calculate my function for first `numberOfThreads` integers of the loop and if one thread finishes its work then next step of the loop is assigned to it. How do I achieve that?**

The thing is a cannot redistribute the work by dividing the for loop into `numberOfThreads` parts, because it is impossible to determine how long the calculation would take for given integer. And redistributing to threads by even parts of the loop could result in one thread finished and another would not even have one tenth of its work done.

Comment: So.. you want a static work queue? I.e. Preload the queue before kicking off the threads, then each thread pulls the next work-detail from the queue and runs with it, coming back for more when its done? Honestly I prefer just dividing up the work and sending a subset to each thread. Unless there are *wildly* different runtimes dependent on `i`, the time a few threads spend not working should be minimal, and the benefit simply cannot be overstated: zero-contention on a latched queue.

Comment: Its the first time I see term static work queue, but your description seems to be exactly my problem. and dividing the work is would really slow this down because there are some configurations which take significantly more time than others, maybe I understated that.

Comment: Then it gets a little more complicated, but if it is that busy on the threads during their work-run, it is likely queue latch time will minuscule. So a work queue can definitely work for this.

Comment: Ok, any hints or references how to implement this?

Comment: Does your toolchain support the [`<atomic>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) operations library? If so you could make a static queue that would be both roaring fast and *simple*. Check your toolchain and post-back.

Comment: I´m not sure if i understand your question, but if you want to know if <atomic> library is available in my project, then the answer is yes

Comment: Then this will probably be simpler than you think. I'll try and post something for you. This isn't going to turn into a lesson on multi-threading, but a simple integration of an atomic-variable and how you can use it to divvy up the work should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Use TBB as explained in [this SO answer][2].


  [1]: https://code.google.com/p/disruptor-cpp/
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607215/simplest-tbb-example

Comment: Ok. posted. I hope it helps you out. Took me a minute to think of something that would spin legitimate CPU cycles to demonstrate the concurrency.

Comment: Contention?  5-500 seconds is a very long time indeed compared with the time taken to pop an object pointer, (or integer), from a queue. sounds like queue contention is a non-issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is one example of how you can do this with an atomic, an affordance that works well if you have a static set of data that needs to be processed. For this sample, I'm building 100 vectors of 100,000 elements each, all of them randomly shuffled, and sending them to the threads for sorting.

Note: I did have to introduce a mutex into this to get the output to stdout to properly not interlace. In reality, it isn't needed if you're not doing interactive output like this. Pay special attention to the output thread ids, and you'll see each thread gets multiple work items, all fairly balanced (because the workload was).

I hope it helps you out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <random>
#include <mutex>

// our work item
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> WorkQueue;

// holds the atomic counter for our vector
std::atomic<std::size_t> cnt = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);
std::mutex mtx;

void thread_proc(WorkQueue& wq)
{
    int count = 0;
    std::size_t n = std::atomic_fetch_add(&cnt, std::size_t(1));
    while (n < wq.size())
    {
        //
        // TODO: do something with the n-th item in the vector
        //
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": item " << n << std::endl;
        lck.unlock();

        std::sort(wq[n].begin(), wq[n].end());
        ++count;

        // increment by one and move to next item
        n = std::atomic_fetch_add(&cnt, std::size_t(1));
    }

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " processed " << count << " items." << std::endl;
    lck.unlock();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine rng(rd());

    // build a sizable work queue.
    WorkQueue wq;

    // make a 100000 element sequence of incrementing numbers
    std::vector<int> item;
    item.reserve(100000);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(item), 100000,
                    [](){ static int i=0; return ++i;});

    // add 100 vectors of 1000000 elements each
    wq.reserve(100);
    for (unsigned i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        // make a unique shuffle for this insertion
        std::shuffle(item.begin(), item.end(), rng);

        // append a random length of values (1000..size);
        long len = 1000 + (rng() % (item.size() - 1000));
        std::cout << "Appending vector of " << len << " items. " << std::endl;
        wq.emplace_back(item.begin(), std::next(item.begin(), len));
    }

    // ok. get the number of threads we're going to be using.
    unsigned n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (unsigned i=0; i<n_threads;++i)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(thread_proc, std::ref(wq)));

    // now join the threads
    for (auto& thrd : threads)
        thrd.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output** (system dependent, obviously)

```
Appending vector of 67742 items. 
Appending vector of 87839 items. 
Appending vector of 13960 items. 
Appending vector of 64161 items. 
Appending vector of 56993 items. 
Appending vector of 30626 items. 
Appending vector of 24970 items. 
Appending vector of 96336 items. 
Appending vector of 2697 items. 
Appending vector of 70087 items. 
Appending vector of 35234 items. 
Appending vector of 82828 items. 
Appending vector of 15808 items. 
Appending vector of 38646 items. 
Appending vector of 55819 items. 
Appending vector of 99380 items. 
Appending vector of 33486 items. 
Appending vector of 9742 items. 
Appending vector of 50267 items. 
Appending vector of 4421 items. 
Appending vector of 33577 items. 
Appending vector of 55888 items. 
Appending vector of 61601 items. 
Appending vector of 19894 items. 
Appending vector of 90217 items. 
Appending vector of 80498 items. 
Appending vector of 40101 items. 
Appending vector of 50601 items. 
Appending vector of 71679 items. 
Appending vector of 65707 items. 
Appending vector of 8671 items. 
Appending vector of 67409 items. 
Appending vector of 47066 items. 
Appending vector of 53989 items. 
Appending vector of 88724 items. 
Appending vector of 82923 items. 
Appending vector of 38571 items. 
Appending vector of 58705 items. 
Appending vector of 13149 items. 
Appending vector of 97816 items. 
Appending vector of 59586 items. 
Appending vector of 20798 items. 
Appending vector of 45906 items. 
Appending vector of 96078 items. 
Appending vector of 24951 items. 
Appending vector of 19954 items. 
Appending vector of 52154 items. 
Appending vector of 49653 items. 
Appending vector of 14830 items. 
Appending vector of 45169 items. 
Appending vector of 96009 items. 
Appending vector of 15941 items. 
Appending vector of 37832 items. 
Appending vector of 55441 items. 
Appending vector of 65057 items. 
Appending vector of 69484 items. 
Appending vector of 27425 items. 
Appending vector of 11579 items. 
Appending vector of 43795 items. 
Appending vector of 71688 items. 
Appending vector of 17214 items. 
Appending vector of 69687 items. 
Appending vector of 18897 items. 
Appending vector of 96105 items. 
Appending vector of 62040 items. 
Appending vector of 26292 items. 
Appending vector of 34464 items. 
Appending vector of 49473 items. 
Appending vector of 83357 items. 
Appending vector of 50406 items. 
Appending vector of 48313 items. 
Appending vector of 22030 items. 
Appending vector of 2352 items. 
Appending vector of 82989 items. 
Appending vector of 42358 items. 
Appending vector of 59134 items. 
Appending vector of 46823 items. 
Appending vector of 36615 items. 
Appending vector of 40752 items. 
Appending vector of 49963 items. 
Appending vector of 73666 items. 
Appending vector of 29816 items. 
Appending vector of 4112 items. 
Appending vector of 31045 items. 
Appending vector of 8810 items. 
Appending vector of 43021 items. 
Appending vector of 83699 items. 
Appending vector of 5551 items. 
Appending vector of 85914 items. 
Appending vector of 11835 items. 
Appending vector of 82329 items. 
Appending vector of 13567 items. 
Appending vector of 74271 items. 
Appending vector of 49083 items. 
Appending vector of 42803 items. 
Appending vector of 92871 items. 
Appending vector of 17562 items. 
Appending vector of 28686 items. 
Appending vector of 61544 items. 
Appending vector of 13375 items. 
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 0
Thread 0x101c46000: item 1
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 2
Thread 0x101e81000: item 3
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 4
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 5
Thread 0x101e81000: item 6
Thread 0x101e81000: item 7
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 8
Thread 0x101c46000: item 9
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 10
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 11
Thread 0x101e81000: item 12
Thread 0x101e81000: item 13
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 14
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 15
Thread 0x101c46000: item 16
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 17
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 18
Thread 0x101c46000: item 19
Thread 0x101c46000: item 20
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 21
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 22
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 23
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 24
Thread 0x101c46000: item 25
Thread 0x101e81000: item 26
Thread 0x101e81000: item 27
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 28
Thread 0x101c46000: item 29
Thread 0x101e81000: item 30
Thread 0x101e81000: item 31
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 32
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 33
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 34
Thread 0x101e81000: item 35
Thread 0x101c46000: item 36
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 37
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 38
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 39
Thread 0x101c46000: item 40
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 41
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 42
Thread 0x101e81000: item 43
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 44
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 45
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 46
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 47
Thread 0x101e81000: item 48
Thread 0x101c46000: item 49
Thread 0x101e81000: item 50
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 51
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 52
Thread 0x101c46000: item 53
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 54
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 55
Thread 0x101c46000: item 56
Thread 0x101e81000: item 57
Thread 0x101c46000: item 58
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 59
Thread 0x101e81000: item 60
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 61
Thread 0x101c46000: item 62
Thread 0x101e81000: item 63
Thread 0x101c46000: item 64
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 65
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 66
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 67
Thread 0x101c46000: item 68
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 69
Thread 0x101e81000: item 70
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 71
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 72
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 73
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 74
Thread 0x101e81000: item 75
Thread 0x101c46000: item 76
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 77
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 78
Thread 0x101e81000: item 79
Thread 0x101c46000: item 80
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 81
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 82
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 83
Thread 0x101e81000: item 84
Thread 0x101e81000: item 85
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 86
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 87
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 88
Thread 0x101e81000: item 89
Thread 0x101e81000: item 90
Thread 0x101c46000: item 91
Thread 0x101c46000: item 92
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 93
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 94
Thread 0x101e81000: item 95
Thread 0x101c46000: item 96
Thread 0x101cc9000: item 97
Thread 0x101bc3000: item 98
Thread 0x101c46000: item 99
Thread 0x101cc9000 processed 24 items.
Thread 0x101c46000 processed 22 items.
Thread 0x101bc3000 processed 30 items.
Thread 0x101e81000 processed 24 items.
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be perfect solution for me. One more question though. Is writing to disc thread safe or do i need to use mutex for this?

Comment: @AdamSikora depends on where you're writing. If it is as you say and al these threads are writing to their own files you  likely have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Shouldn't `n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();` be something like `n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() == 0? 2: std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` since `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` might also return 0 if the information is unavailable thus making the code unrunable on some other machine?