# Class of TBB call functions of another class

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb

I am new to TBB. I met a problem, I hope you guys can give me some advise.

A class named Fruit:

**Fruit.hpp:**

```
class Fruit {
    protected :
        void A(...);
        void B(..);

    public :
        Fruit();
        ~ Fruit();
        void l1(....);
        void l2(...);
};
```

**Fruit.cpp:**

```
custom_TBB (...){
   //How to call the method A of Fruit?
}
class Fruit {
   ...
   Fruit::l1(....){
      tbb::task_scheduler_init init(numberOfThreads);
      parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0,End,10000),custom_TBB (...));
   }
   ...
};
```

Because I need to use parallel method in the function of **l1**.
I am not sure whether my understanding of TBB is right to not?
I would like to know how can I make this works?
Thank you first.

*This is my idea:

1. I tried to declare custom_TBB inside the class Fruit, and implement it here, but failed.

2. I tried to define custom_TBB inside the function of l1, but also failed.*

Comment: What do you mean "failed".  Failed to compile?  Failed to set the number of threads to what you expected?

Comment: @timday Cannot call member function without object -> error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest TBB example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607215/simplest-tbb-example)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should declare that `tbb::task_scheduler_init init(numberOfThreads);` as soon as you can in your program.  I generally have it as pretty much the first thing in the `main()` function of anything I do using TBB.

Comment: Yes, this is a good point, I need actually move it to the main class, thank you. And how about the problem? you have some good ideas?

Comment: For the other aspect, this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10607215/24283

Comment: Thank you for your help! timeday, I think I need to know a lot basic stuff things