# OpenCV forEach function parallel access

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, foreach, htop

I'm processing `RGB` images and doing the same thing for each channel (R+G+B) so I've been looking for parallel functions that could help me improve my code and run it (3*?) faster. Now Im using `forEach` function like so:

```
unsigned char lut[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    lut[i] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(pow((float)(i / 255.0), fGamma) * 255.0f); //pow: power exponent

dst.forEach<cv::Vec3b> //dst is an RGB image
(
    [&lut](cv::Vec3b &pixel, const int* po) -> void
    {
        pixel[0] = lut[(pixel[0])];
        pixel[1] = lut[(pixel[1])];
        pixel[2] = lut[(pixel[2])];
    }
);
```

But when I use `htop` to see the number of threads running, I only find one or two threads on..

[image: htop]

Am I doing something wrong or `forEach` isn't suppose to run on `multi-threading`? Do you have any resources to help me with to get to `multi-threading` computations?

I'm running my code on ubuntu with this:

```
g++ -std=c++1z -Wall -Ofast -march=native test3.cpp -o test3 `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: Seems platform specific. What version of OpenCV? On Windows with v3.1.0 it will fully uses all the cores.

Comment: @DanMašek I'm using OpenCV 3.3 on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look in [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-generic-parallel-algorithms) already? Threading Building Blocks is an apache licensed lib for parallel computing which you can use just compiling OpenCV with the flag -D WITH_TBB=ON

See this example of parallel_for: http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/opencv-with-tbb

If you decide to adopt TBB follow these steps:

1 - Rebuild OpenCV with TBB support. If you are running into a Linux machine just do:

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON BUILD_TBB=ON ..

2 - Rewrite your program to use TBB

See the answers there: [Simplest TBB example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607215/simplest-tbb-example) focusing in the most recent ones.

Comment: I figured out that I didn't activate TBB so I'm gonna do it now. Should I just install opencv with the flag and then recompile my program or I need to implement the functions from TBB lib?