# Why is c++ foreach slower than naive single thread loop?

Tags: c++, opencv

My code is like this:

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int t{0}; t < 100; ++t) {
        vector<int> table(256, 0);
        Mat im2 = cv::imread(impth, cv::ImreadModes::IMREAD_COLOR);
        im2.forEach<cv::Vec3b>([&table](cv::Vec3b &pix, const int* pos) {
                for (int i{0}; i < 3; ++i) ++table[pix[i]];
        });
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "time is: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << endl;

    auto t3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int t{0}; t < 100; ++t) {
        vector<int> table(256, 0);
        Mat im2 = cv::imread(impth, cv::ImreadModes::IMREAD_COLOR);
        for (int r{0}; r < im2.rows; ++r) {
            auto ptr = im2.ptr<uint8_t>(r);
            for (int c{0}; c < im2.cols; ++c) {
                for (int i{0}; i < 3; ++i) ++table[ptr[i]];
                ptr += 3;
            }
        }
    }
    auto t4 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "time is: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t4 - t3).count() << endl;
```

Intuitively, I feel that `foreach` should work faster since it used multi-thread mechanism to do the work, but the result turns out that the `foreach` methods took 14759ms while the naive loop method took only 6791ms. What is the cause of this slower `foreach` method, and how could make it faster ?

Comment: When I tried it, foreach is faster almost 30 milisecond

Comment: Does it foreach one actually work? Looks like you're writing concurrently to `table` with no synchronization (and you'll bounce that vector all over your cores with concurrent writes).

Comment: `foreach` use of threads depends on how the opencv library is built.   If it is built without support of multithreading, then the benefits of multithreading won't be observed.   Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800790/opencv-foreach-function-parallel-access for more information.

Comment: @Peter I didn't build with TBB, but from my observation, when I use `foreach` to implement similar function such as `LUT`, I can observe from the output of `htop` that multiple cpu cores are used, does this mean that multi-threading is enabled ?

Comment: Are you using optimised code?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I used -O2 option in my CMakeLists.txt: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11, -O2")`, will this work?