# Linking to TBB libraries with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, ld, tbb

I have `tbb` downloaded and placed in my repository directory:

```sh
> tree deps/tbb/ -d 
deps/tbb/
├── bin
├── cmake
│   └── templates
├── include
│   ├── serial
│   │   └── tbb
│   └── tbb
│       ├── compat
│       ├── internal
│       └── machine
└── lib
    ├── ia32
    │   └── gcc4.8
    └── intel64
        └── gcc4.8
```

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have tried this:

```
include_directories("deps/tbb/include")


find_library(TBB_LIB
    NAMES
    tbbbind_debug
    tbbbind
    tbb_debug
    tbbmalloc_debug
    tbbmalloc_proxy_debug
    tbbmalloc_proxy
    tbbmalloc
    tbb_preview_debug
    tbb_preview
    tbb
    HINTS "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/deps/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8"
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
src/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${TBB_LIB})
```

But building with `cmake`, linker throws this error:

> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lTBB_LIB-NOTFOUND
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I couldn't figure out what is missing. Thanks.

## Update

This commit resolves the previous error:

```
-    HINTS "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/deps/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8"
+    HINTS "deps/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8"
```

But, new errors are thrown:

> undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_current_slot()'

## Update

Other than `find_library`, what CMake tools are available to link to TBB shared libraries?

I have tried some CMake tools, but I cannot figure out how to link to TBB `*.so` files correctly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by @AlexReinking answer, here is the final implementation:

```
    project(my-cpp-service VERSION 0.1.0)

    # Equivalent to command-line option of `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=...`
    list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "deps/tbb/cmake/")

    find_package(TBB REQUIRED)

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        src/main.cpp
    )

    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        TBB::tbb
    )
```

Answer (score 14):

TBB has native CMake support. On my system with the Intel oneAPI installed, the config package is installed here:

```
/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest/lib/cmake/tbb/TBBConfig.cmake
```

Therefore, I just need to add `/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest` to my `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. In my CMakeLists.txt, I wrote this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test-tbb)

find_package(TBB REQUIRED)

add_library(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE TBB::tbb)
target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
```

TBB provides the IMPORTED target `TBB::tbb`, which is what you should link to.

main.cpp is just the source from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36782794/2137996

Build like so:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/latest
$ cmake --build build --verbose
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++  -isystem /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.3.0/include  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/alex/test2/main.cpp
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libmain.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libmain.a  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libmain.a && :
```

Answer (score -1):

This post helped me solved the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/3405291

The errors got resolved by:

```
include_directories("deps/tbb/include")

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/3405291
find_library(LIB_TBB                NAMES tbb               HINTS "deps/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8")
find_library(LIB_TBBbind            NAMES tbbbind           HINTS "deps/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8")
find_library(LIB_TBBmalloc_proxy    NAMES tbbmalloc_proxy   HINTS "deps/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8")
find_library(LIB_TBBmalloc          NAMES tbbmalloc         HINTS "deps/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8")
find_library(LIB_TBB_preview        NAMES tbb_preview       HINTS "deps/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
src/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
${LIB_TBB}
${LIB_TBBbind}
${LIB_TBBmalloc_proxy}
${LIB_TBBmalloc}
${LIB_TBB_preview}
)
```

Comment: No. Do not do this. Use `find_package` and imported targets.

Comment: @AlexReinking Alright =) Thanks!